# Simple relation decomposition example - insufficient information?

Tags: database, relational-database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

The entire question is:

> The relation R(A, B, C, D, E) with F = {A→B ; A→C ; B,D→A} is decomposed considering the functional dependency A→B from the beginning.
>
> What is the functional dependency that cannot be preserved by such a decomposition?

It seems to me that I have insufficient data to answer this question. Firstly, doesn't knowing which FD cannot be preserved depend on the normal form we are using? Secondly, the decomposition is unfinished; doesn't the preservation depend on which decomposition we use?

Comment: It was a question on an assignment in my university database course.

Comment: Hi. That part I already figured. Relevant details? What in your textbook & lectures had to do with this? What does "considering" mean here? Is this translated to English? Anyway the language is not clear. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The question is certainly poorly phrased. Presumably F is supposed to be a cover for the FDs that hold in R--ie the FDs that hold in R are the ones implied by the ones in F. It's not clear what is meant by "decomposed considering the functional dependency A → B from the beginning". We would reasonably say that "decomposing considering a FD" means decomposing introducing a component with the FD's attributes. I suspect that they are trying to say, if you binary decompose to component AB plus some other component(s) then what FD "cannot be preserved by such a decomposition"?

When we losslessly decompose we really mean we are only interested in decompositions where all the components are smaller than the original & no component is a subset of another. So in a decomposition having component AB the other components would join to either ACDE or BCDE.

Look at the remaining given FDs: A → C & B, D → A. For each of those projections/components, if it were losslessly joinable with AB then the FDs that are implied by those per Armstrong's axioms & that have all their attributes in it will hold in it. (And no others will hold in it.) But there's one of those two FDs that can't hold in either of the two projections. So that's the one that "cannot be preserved by such a decomposition".

> Firstly, doesn't knowing which FD cannot be preserved depend on the normal form we are using?

They seem to be trying to ask about a decomposition of a certain nature, so the resulting NFs don't matter.

> Secondly, the decomposition is unfinished; doesn't the preservation depend on which decomposition we use?

They are telling you that a certain FD "cannot be preserved by such a decomposition". So we can expect that as long as we have "such a decomposition" the answer doesn't further "depend on which decomposition we use".

(Note that a decomposition to 2NF or 3NF can fail to preserve FDs. But there's always a decomposition that doesn't fail.)